# Create new textfile with same name as other files

Tags: command-line, powershell

I have a bunch of files in a folder. I need to create text files. 
Every text file must have the same (base) *name* as one of the files in the folder, but with a `.txt` extension instead of the current one. 
Also in every new text file the filename itself must be placed on the first line.

For example, in a folder there are:

```
filename 1.dim
filename 2.dim
```

Need to create new textfiles

```
filename 1.txt
filename 2.txt
```

content of textfiles:

- `filename 1.txt` should have a line that reads `filename 1.dim`
- `filename 2.txt` should have a line that reads `filename 2.dim`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I'd process only files with the `.dim` extension
- check if the file (with more content) already exists

```
## Q:\Test\2019\07\05\SU_1456413.ps1
Set-Location 'A:\Test'
foreach($File in Get-ChildItem *.dim){
    $Name=$File.BaseName+'.txt'
    if(!(Test-Path $Name -PathType Leaf)){
        New-Item $Name -Value $File.Name
    } else {
        "File {0} already exists" -f $Name
    }
}
```

---

```
PoSh 13:08:51 A:\test____________________________
> Select-String filename*.txt -Pattern filename

filename 1.txt:1:filename 1.dim
filename 2.txt:1:filename 2.dim
```

Answer (score 0):

`cd` into the folder before running the following:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem
foreach($file in $files){
$name = [io.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
New-Item -Path . -Name $name+".txt" -ItemType "file" -Value [io.Path]::GetFileName($file)
}
```